# Артефакты на текстурах при удалении на большое расстояние от них OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

Столкнулся с проблемой, что когда далеко отлетаешь от объекта, на который наложена текстура, появляются странные искажения (при зумировании самой камеры заметно)...Не могу понять, с чем это связано...Mipmapping отключал, эффект тот же..
Текстуры накладываю с такими параметрами(их тоже менял, не смог пофиксить проблему):

```
glGenerateMipmap(_textureType);
glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(_textureType, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не хватает разрешающей способности Z-буфера.

Comment: Как-то можно пофиксить или просто смириться?

Comment: Посмотрите z-near и z-far. Когда вы рендерите планету далеко, можно рендерить её в текстуру, а  z-near/z-far настроить так чтобы они были недалеко от планеты. Кончится всё тем что вы разобъёте все объекты по планам (крупный, средний, мельче, ещё мельче и т.п.). Каждый план отредерите со своим диапазоном z и наложите их. Как-то так.

Comment: Но прежде чем браться вы проверьте что настройка Z-буфера поможет. Вдруг я не угадал. :)

Comment: Ну вот я сделал
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
Что по сути эквивалентно отключению Z-буффера, и никаких артефактов нет, только всё отображается априори криво из-за нерабочего Z-буффера)

Comment: `Face culling` включен? Планеты выпуклые, face culling улучшит рендеринг даже с грубым z-буфером.

Comment: Попробуйте задать Z-buffer поточнее, 24 или даже 32 бита.

Comment: Да там и на небольшом расстоянии полно артефактов. А для рисования сферы z-buffer не нужен.

Comment: @Kromster, как это сделать?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, мне нужно включить, получается, только вывод передних граней?

Comment: @ГлебТруфанов, да. Это почти в два раза быстрее при рендеринге. Меньше хлопот с точность z-буфера.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, проблема решилась)) Интересно, есть ли ещё способы решения данной проблемы практически в одну строчку...без использования трафарета буфера и тд

Comment: Это врождённый недостаток z-буфера ограниченной разрядности. Хорошие спецы знают об этом и заранее готовятся. Теперь и вы будете готовится, что сделает вас лучшим спецом. У вас, кстати, планеты на краю вселенной форму не теряют?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, что значит "на краю вселенной" ?)
Ничего не теряется вроде, всё красиво

Comment: Когда координаты центра планеты подбираются к границе мантисы, вершины мешей теряют точность и начинают произвольно скакать. Вычитание больших почти равных вещественных числе - catastrophic cancellation. Большая полуось Нептуна 4503443661000м. Следите за руками: `4503443661000 - 4503443661000.1 = -0.099609375`. На таком расстоянии ошибки округления порядка миллиметра для double. Пока не катастрофа. Но планету можно отодвинуть так далеко от начала координат, что ошибки округления буду сравнимы с её радиусом. Вот тогда она не отрендерится нормально даже если камера рядом.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, уф...Я такие большие числа не использую для рендера планет, слишком уж жирно будет)) У меня просто курсовая работа по графике, где я делаю красивую сцену Солнечной системы, но, думаю, даже в "продакшн" коде (в какой-нибудь игре, к примеру) "реальный по размеру" рендер планет не очень нужен, слишком уж большими они будут))

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась просто отсечением задних граней

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

Но на самом деле это не единственный вариант, если есть какие-нибудь ещё, то вопрос открыт)
Так же можно сдвигать ближнюю плоскость отсечения в зависимости от расстояния до объекта (менять предпоследний параметр)

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), monitorAspect, 0.1f, 300000.0f);
```